# Regex pattern matching C#

Tags: c#, regex

[image: Here is the picture]

I want to loop through each file in a folder and save the substring of the file name to a variable.

For example lets say I have the following file in a folder:

ERISRequest_INC1234567.csv //Should Print -> INC1234567

ERISRequest_INC8901234.csv //Should print -> INC8901234

fileName.csv //should skip this one

I want to extract the shown substring if and only if the file name starts with ERISRequest_ and store it in a variable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
            foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name).StartsWith("ERISRequest_")) {...}`

Comment: To follow on from what Dmitry said, you can then use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) to deal with the file extension

Comment: It doesnt print it on the console I add the condition inside the for each loop

Comment: @whatever11938: what are the files' names printed out without any condition, please?

Comment: It does not print anything, the code I posted prints all file names

Comment: So you have `c:\ERISRequest_INC1234567.csv, c:\ERISRequest_INC8901234.csv, c:\fileName.csv' printed by your origin code?

Comment: If I have the following files in the folder: 
EIRSRequest_INC1234567.csv AND

EIRSRequest_INC8901234.csv

It prints the complete file name with extension:

 EIRSRequest_INC1234567.csv

 EIRSRequest_INC8901234.csv

Comment: If you run the code from the main method in [this example](http://rextester.com/VYPR55085) you don't see anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** Now, Try this, in C#.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"ERISRequest_(?<val>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})");
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            var match = regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["val"].Value);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: yours worked but I dont want the .csv. It should not give me the extension.

Comment: change the first line to                                                                                   
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"ERISRequest_(?<val>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}).csv");

Answer (score 0):

Get the file name without the extension and then check it starts with your prefix.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Quicky
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string PREFIX = "ERISRequest_";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                if (fi.Name.StartsWith(PREFIX))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name).Substring(PREFIX.Length));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @whatever11938 Yeah my bad. Forgot to add the substring line in for some reason. That should work now

Answer (score 0):

It helps you. Is that what you're looking for?

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"ERISRequest_(?<val>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})");
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        var match = regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["val"].Value);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: ERISRequest_INC8901234.csv file]

[image: Result on console]

Comment: doesnt seem to print anything

Comment: There is no reason for it is not working i think. I runned on my computer an it worked. Are there any error or etc..

Comment: that is not what I want... I tried again and it doesnt work

Comment: @whatever11938 is it possible there is no file to match with `regstr`?

Comment: Here is an example of what I want:

ERISRequest_INC1234567.csv //Should Print -> INC1234567

ERISRequest_INC8901234.csv //Should print -> INC8901234

fileName.csv //should skip this one

Comment: opens up the console window but doesnt print anything

Comment: @whatever11938 so there is no such file there :)

Comment: @whatever11938 please give an example i am going to try that for you

Comment: ERISRequest_INC8901234.csv

try this example

Comment: @whatever11938 i have just updated pics, check it please :)

Comment: hey I edited my post and added pictures could you tell me what I am doing wrong it still doesnt work for me

Comment: does the file have to bee on desktop or something ?

Comment: @whatever11938 My files is the same directory with you. In my opinion we have to look your code step by step. Could you print all file name in your  _"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\App\ER\L E P\L E D"_ directory to your console.

Comment: yes the original code I posted printed all file names

Comment: Can you post an image from your directory @whatever11938

Comment: Thaks for sharing, but i wish i could see the file on your directory. I guess your directory path is currect or exists on your machine otherwise you would get an error `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`. So we have to sure that your files are matching with our regex pattern. I think the problem is that. I create folder according to your scenario but i really wonder to see your file. Why is regex matching with my folders and why not matching with yours. @whatever11938

Comment: Files:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FfTtI0TtF3Del4GZevAGRVdsXv9F0tFT

Code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MwYeziTK_tb4hr72ZQbRtl4xtdc_PGqx

Comment: You changed your directory :))  I can not believe that before I work on your computer :) But you have check on debug mode your file names and character, sometimes there may be a special character somewhere and it makes crazy. Except those I do not know what to say. @whatever11938

Comment: See the answer by Ajeet Kumar. It works but it is also giving me the extension

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575216/regex-pattern-matching-c-sharp/51577074#51577074

Comment: I edited Ajeet Kumar answer and mine also. You can try with this, file extension dont have to seen on console. @whatever11938

Comment: can I save each filename in a variable instead of printing it?